# Where to put folders for code in docker containers

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, docker

I have currently 6 websites running in VPS and i want to convert them to docker.

One thing which is confusing me is that how should i arrange the persistent storage folders on host.

E,g

These are the types of folders i want to have access from host

1. Code folders which i can put in `Projects/site1` `Projects/site2`
2. Then i have configuration files like apache, supervisor, nginx, which i can put with Dockerfile but again i am not sure should they all be in code folder to put them in version control
3. The third is Mysql and Psql Data folders which currently i am thinkinf `/DATA/psql` and `/DATA/mysql`

Which way should i go  in production. so there should never be anything inside containers which need to edit

Answer (score 0):

You could do data volumes or data container. Here is the documentation you can read: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

This way, you can store the data on your host! Don't need to worry about losing the data by accidentally stop or remove the container!